# Select All Checkboxs 'when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a lot of trouble trying to select all checkboxs with a click of a button.

As I am creating a messaging system, I am using PHP  while loop to generate all of the checkboxes and have no problem with that.

When I click the <kbd>Check All</kbd> button, it will only check the first checkbox, any other checkbox below is ignored for some reason.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
<button type='button' name='btn-check' id='btn-check' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick='check()'>Check All</button>

<input type='checkbox' name='cb_delete[]' id='cb_delete' value='$mID'>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function check() {
     document.getElementById("cb_delete").checked = true;
     $("#btn-check").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#btn-uncheck").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#btn-delete").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
   }
</script>
```

I have tried changing `getElementById`, to `getElementByType`, `ByName`, etc and still no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is (most probably) that you're using the same `id` attribute for each `checkbox`.
[The `id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) is meant to be an *identifier* and as such, **must be unique** in the whole document.

Try to use `class` instead of `id`:

```
<button type='button' name='btn-check' id='btn-check' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>Check All</button>

<input type='checkbox' name='cb_delete[]' class='cb_delete' value='$mID'>
```

Script:

```
$("#btn-check").click(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $("#btn-uncheck").removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.cb_delete').prop('checked', true);
});
```

---

On a side note - [It's not a good practice to use `onClick` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explaination. Fixed my problem! Very kind of you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yohcjvkL/)

Since you are using jQuery you can resolve this by replacing

`document.getElementById("cb_delete").checked = true;`

with

`$(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);`